# How can I dereference this 2D dynamic array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

I am having issues with dereferencing the 2D dynamic array in the if statement's condition on line 5.

```
typedef char* CharArrayPtr;

void reserveSeat(CharArrayPtr *m, char row, char seatLetter){
    for(int j = 1; j < 5; j++){
        if(m[row - 1][j] == seatLetter)
            m[row - 1][j] = 'X';
    }
}
```

I've tried putting the * in front, but I get this error message:

*Indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)*

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `CharArrayPtr`

Comment: Also explain what issues you are having exactly. Include exact text of any relevant compiler error messages or runtime errors

Comment: Added the definition for `CharArrayPtr` above.

Comment: When i build and run, the compiler stops at that line. I assume its an error with how it thinks I am comparing an address to a char value.

Comment: @borninla That is not the error.  Your error is somewhere else, most likely a mismanagement of that `m` variable you're passing to the function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ok, will check and get back to you

Comment: the compiler doesn't do anything once you run.  If there was an error with types you would ge ta message at compile-time, not a runtime.  what do you mean by "the compiler stops" ?

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you mean to dereference the 2D array by operator *, please try following.

```
typedef char* CharArrayPtr;

void reserveSeat(CharArrayPtr *m, char row, char seatLetter){
    for(int j = 1; j < 5; j++){
        //if(m[row - 1][j] == seatLetter)
        if( *( (char*)m + (row - 1)*5 + j ) == seatLetter)
            m[row - 1][j] = 'X';
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not passed m as a 2D array you have used a single pointer.

void reserveSeat(CharArrayPtr **m, char row, char seatLetter)

and to derefer it use *(*(w+i)+j);